# Kubuntu 11.04 bad experience, Gimp crashes and other bugs

Tags: kubuntu, gimp

I installed Kubuntu 11.04 64bit today.

First let me expose some issues, this is not a rant, just some observations on Kubuntu 11.04 :)

- Flash doesn't work. The package "flashplugin-installer" was installed by rekonq. But still no flash.
- Additional Drivers (jockey-kde) doesn't show up automatically after first login.
- I tried to delete a large file (19,2 GB), an error appeared: "Please empty the trash first, no more space available" or something like that, but you know what? My trash was empty! (Then I found in Dolphin the settings to increment the max size of the trash).
- Amarok has no play/pause/forward/back buttons, only after changing settings to show those buttons on the top bar.
- GTK applications like ubuntu software center, inkscape... are in english, but my default language is "german". Only gimp allows to install the "de" language pack.
- The numblock turns off after each restart. In the KDE Control Center, the "remember last state" of numblock is set. But this is not working.
- I had some crashes: Nepomuk, Policy-kit, plasma-workspace and gimp.

But now to the important stuff. I really need Gimp to work. After starting it, I get a crash:

giowck@giowck-desktop:~$ gimp

(gimp:1899): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.28.6/./glib/goption.c:2132: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (8) on option of type 0
Speicherzugriffsfehler (in English: "Memory error")

What can I do to run Gimp?

Thanks

Comment: just a thought... this isnt exactly the place to rant about bad experiences with ubuntu.  On another note, have you tried reinstalling gimp?  `sudo apt-get remove --purge gimp; sudo apt-get install gimp`

Comment: You should file bug reports for your encountered errors and criticism. I edited your question to remove the rants, so my edits might be approved soon, but I pastebined your rants at http://pastebin.com/rHnSp9x3 for your future reference.

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix: I just tried that, still won't work. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @ Thomay Boxley, I think It's not ok to edit in such a heavy way my "post". But I recognize that this is the wrong place for opinions.

Comment: I edited my original post by removing the opinions. Now they are only observations :P

Comment: FYI @giowck, if you post a question or an answer, you have just agreed to let your items be mercilessly edited.  Just sayin is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a weird error in GIMP that causes the crash.

you have to goto your System Settings > Application Appearance > GTK+ Appearance and change the Widget style to Raleigh.

now start GIMP once and you can change the the GTK+ style back to whatever you want

weird but it works

as for your other issues, try adding the [kubuntu ppa's](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa) to you repos as there are monthly updates that sort out many of the issues you're having, especially with amarok

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! I'll activate the kubuntu ppa :D

Comment: glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Gimp still works after switching back to oxygen-gtk style. I don't know if is due the kubuntu ppa... Anyway flash works again, after reinstalling flashplugin-installer. Seems someone fixed it!