# GIMP crashes on startup

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu

First, I must say that I do not have PPA or any experimental packages enabled.

Just now I installed the GIMP using kpackagekit. When I tried to start it using icon in the application menu, it didn't start.

I tried running it from the terminal, and it said that it crashed with a segmentation fault.

The question is : is there anything that I can do to install (or reinstall it) properly? I am sure they wouldn't release it if it was crashing like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google revealed this](http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3116721.msg262098#msg262098) - as an aside - weirdest solution I've seen - but a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/757653)

Set your gtk appearance to Raleigh, launch Gimp once, and then change back to whatever theme you were using before.

i.e.

1. Click System Settings - Application Appearance -
2. Click on GTK+ Appearance and change Widget Style from oxygen-gtk to Raleigh.
3. Click Apply.
4. Start Gimp and Close
5. Repeat the above by switch back from Raleigh to oxygen-gtk

Comment: similar to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/51294/kubuntu-11-04-bad-experience-gimp-crashes-and-other-bugs/51381#51381